# "Upgrade" path from Windows 7 RTM 90-day trial to full version

Tags: windows-7, license

I have installed a 90 day trial version of Windows 7. What is going to happy at the end of 90 days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the Windows 7 Enterprise 90-day trial you're talking about, you're going to need to reinstall after the trial period is up. From [Microsoft TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/cc442495.aspx):

> - The 90-day Trial is the full working version of the Windows 7 Enterprise,
>   the version most of you will be
>   working with in your corporate
>   environment. It will not require a
>   product key (it is embedded with the
>   download).
> - The 90-day Trial will shut down once every hour when you have reached the end of the 90-day evaluation period.
> - The 90-day Trial is offered for a limited time and in limited quantity. The download will be available through March 31, 2010, while supplies last.
> - After the 90-day Trial expires, if you wish to continue to use Windows 7
>   Enterprise, please note that **you will
>   be required to purchase and perform a
>   clean installation of Windows 7,
>   including drivers and applications.**
>   Please keep this in mind; Windows 7
>   Enterprise is not available through
>   retail channels.

Comment: there's a window somewhere (i can't remember where right now, i'm at work) that seems like it would let you change the product id, which would make me thing that that would work...